# Time-series clustering in python: DBSCAN and OPTICS giving me strange results

Tags: python, scikit-learn, time-series, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I want to perform **clustering** on **time-series** data. I use Python's Sklearn library for the project. At first, I created a distance matrix by using dynamic time warping (**DTW**). Then I clustered the data using **OPTICS** function in sklearn like this:

```
clustering = OPTICS(min_samples=3, max_eps=0.7, cluster_method='dbscan', metric="precomputed").fit(distance_matrix)
```

Then I visualized this distances using **MDS** like the following:

```
mds = MDS(n_components=2, dissimilarity="precomputed").fit(distance_matrix)
```

And this is the result:
[image: clustering results]

The dark blue points are the outliers and the other two are the clusters identified by optics. I cannot understand these results. The yellow points cluster doesn't make any sense. I played with numbers and changed them but it always gives strange results. This is the same when I use DBSCAN but for K-MEANS and AGNES, I get more reasonable clusters when I visualize them. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: got sample data?

Comment: points might overlap, so best is to use alpha when plotting. if you have sample data I can take a look as well. Also- notice the scale change of x and y

Comment: @user3184950 I'm sorry can you explain what do you mean by using alpha? The input data is daily new cases of COVID-19 for the countries all around the world. It's extracted from JHU github account:  https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/tree/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series

Comment: transparency for point, to easy detect overlapping points. With the alpha=.5 you can make points/lines transparent. sometimes there is a point hidden behind a other one, and with alpha they become visible

Comment: Perhaps good to see the whole code and data together.